# Adding a page inside a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the follwoing javascript which is used in a quiz that will show a different page absed on the answers. I would the page to appear in a modal box. My pages are called opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4

Is is possible to do this?

Code:

```
function finish() {
var ext = '';
var results = new Array("none","opt1","opt2","opt3","opt4");
var nums = new Array(5);
for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) nums[i] = 0;
for(var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    var q = document.forms['quiz'].elements['question_'+i];
    if(q[0].type=='checkbox') {
        var n = 0;
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < q.length; j++) {
        if(q[j].checked) {
            var a = q[j].value.split(',');
            for(var k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
                nums[a[k]]++;
            }
            if(q[j].type=='radio') break;
            else n++;
        }
        if(j == q.length-1&&q[j].type=='radio') {nums[0]++;}
    }
    if(q[0].type=='checkbox'&&((document.forms['quiz'].elements['question_'+i+'_min']&&n<document.forms['quiz'].elements['question_'+i+'_min'].value)||(document.forms['quiz'].elements['question_'+i+'_max']&&n>document.forms['quiz'].elements['question_'+i+'_max'].value))) nums[0]++;
}
var j = new Array('0');
for (i in nums) if(nums[i]>nums[j[0]]){j=new Array(''+i);} else if(nums[i]==nums[j[0]])j[j.length] = i;
//var o = '';for(var i in results)o+=results[i]+'='+nums[i]+'\n';
//alert(o);
if(nums[0]!=0) {
    alert('You missed or incorrectly answered '+nums[0]+' questions!');
}
else if(j[0]==0) {
    alert('No result could be determined.');
}
else {
    location = results[j[0]]+ext;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `page`; an HTML document? Does using `iframe`s work for you? What `modal` library are you using (if any)?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen...thanks Im using Wordpress and light box for the modal